# Can a 'lone wolf' soldier be mind controlled?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I'm about to start a new game, and I plan on getting the Lone Wolf achievement.

Question; if you only have one soldier on the field (either by choice, or because the rest die) - can you still be mind controlled?

Comment: I don't see why not - it should just skip your turn until the mind control wears off.

Comment: I believe you lose immediately, actually.

Comment: ... Bah, unfair. If I MC the last surviving alien I have to wait until it wears off and then shoot him.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was going for this achievement on classic difficulty and when my soldier got MC'd by an ethereal (with 2 Muton Elites running around) the mission ended immediately.

Comment: I've changed my answer to this. Having now actually confronted this situation - I can confirm if your sole remaining unit is mind-controlled - then it is mission over.

Answer (score 5):

I've seen my sole remaining soldier get mind controlled before, and then be returned to me a couple of turns later.  On easier difficulties this is more survivable, since mind control might just move you into a stupid position.

In my case, I was mind-controlled by a single remaining enemy, who decided to make my soldier hide around a corner until I eventually got the chance to come back and get the kill.

Comment: Sorry Dan - but this is incorrect. I just had this happen to me, and my mission ended automatically.

Answer (score 0):

My first win on Ironman normal my psionically specially boosted heavy was the last one alive and got mindcontrolled by the final boss. Awoke two turns later standing next to it, and after a mild panic shot it twice at 66% to win the game. I don't know if this is a special case for the specially boosted soldier on the last mission though.